# Search files with same part of content in linux

Tags: linux, bash, file, grep, comparison

Here is the problem. I have a huge number of files(10000 or more) in one folder. Every file contains it's own ID on position from 26th to 36th symbol.
I need to find all files with the same IDs.
E.g. there can be files with IDs 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 and I want to get result in a list

1. files 1.txt, 2.txt - id 1
2. files 4.txt, 5.txt - id 3

Thought about using `grep` but I'm not very good with bash scripts to make it work as I wish.

File looks like

```
some headercontentskipped1231231231231231231231someothercontent
```

BMW's anser helps, but displays all files
in outpul like

```
files 1 - Copy (10).txt,1 - Copy (12).txt,1 - Copy (13).txt,1 - Copy (14).txt,1 - Copy (15).txt,1 - Copy (2).txt,1 - Copy (3).txt,1 - Copy (4).txt,1 - Copy (5).txt,1 - Copy (6).txt,1 - Copy (7).txt,1 - Copy (8).txt,1 - Copy (9).txt,1 - Copy.txt,1.txt - id 6123123123
files 1 - Copy (11).txt - id 6222123123
```

But I don't need info about files, that don't have another files with same IDs

Comment: Show example about your txt file.

Comment: To just extract the ID you could do `grep -Pom1 '^.{25}\K.{10}' files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess. If the ID is always at first line in each file. Here is the code.

```
awk 'FNR==1{ id=substr($0,26,10)
             a[id]=(a[id]=="")?FILENAME:a[id] OFS FILENAME
             b[id]++}
     END{ for (i in a) if (b[i]>1) printf "files %s - id %s\n",a[i],i }' OFS="," *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but is there a way to exclude from output files, which don't have same IDs with any other files?

Comment: I think I could missexplain you, sorry. Now the result of this script shows all files

Comment: And I want only the "same-id" files to be shown...
E.g. now it looks like
files 1 - Copy (10).txt,1 - Copy (12).txt,1 - Copy (13).txt,1 - Copy (14).txt,1 - Copy (15).txt,1 - Copy (2).txt,1 - Copy (3).txt,1 - Copy (4).txt,1 - Copy (5).txt,1 - Copy (6).txt,1 - Copy (7).txt,1 - Copy (8).txt,1 - Copy (9).txt,1 - Copy.txt,1.txt - id 6123123123
files 1 - Copy (11).txt - id 6222123123

Comment: put it in your original question with format, such as what I did. Seems your file name are something like `1-Copy (NN).txt`. the result looks fine for me. the id `6123123123` exist in many files. Do you mean I needn't report the file `1 - Copy (11).txt`, because it is only one , no other same id file?

Comment: Yes, totally what I'm talking about

Comment: Updated, it will exclude the id which only in one file.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
And the last question. If files will become more complicated, is there a possibility to use some REGEX instead os substr()?

Comment: @LeYar it would be best to use `match` for regex if you want to capture the matched string.

Comment: @LeYar yes, awk supports REGEX very well.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought i would add a slightly different awk

```
awk '{c=FILENAME;b=substr($0,26,10);a[b]=(b in a)?a[b]","c:c;nextfile}
      END{for(i in a)print ++x". "a[i],"- id "i}' *.txt
```

#### Input

`1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt,5.txt` contain

```
some headercontentskipped1231231231231231231231someothercontent
```

`6.txt,7.txt` contain

```
some headercontentskipped22212312331231231231someothercontent
```

#### output

```
1. 6.txt,7.txt - id 2221231233
2. 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt,5.txt - id 1231231231
```

### EDIT

For not showing files if they are the only one with an ID(i think thats what OP wants)

```
     awk '{c=FILENAME;b=substr($0,26,10);a[b]=(b in a)?a[b]","c:c;nextfile}
           END{for(i in a)if(index(a[i],","))print ++x". "a[i],"- id "i}' *.txt
```

#### Input

`1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt,5.txt` contain

```
some headercontentskipped1231231231231231231231someothercontent
```

`6.txt,7.txt` contain

```
some headercontentskipped22212312331231231231someothercontent
```

`8.txt` contains

```
some headercontentskipped212312331231231231someothercontent
```

#### output

```
1. 6.txt,7.txt - id 2221231233
2. 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt,5.txt - id 1231231231
```

Comment: Maybe the reason in some files without same IDs, but you script doesn't display anything as result and don't even finishes without Ctrl+C

Comment: did you put the names of the files at the end ? You obviously have to pass the files to the awk command...

Comment: Ow, that fixed the problem.
But yet a question is not to display files that don't have same IDs with any other